# Set Webpart properties using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, 2016, jsom

I would like to set the webpart properties like height and width with JavaScript to fit content!

FYI: I don't know the web Part ID , I know the web part title

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online, the web part will adjust the width and height to fit zone by default like the picture below.

[image]
If you want to change the width and height of the web part, you could select “Yes” and type the value of the width and height when editing the web part.

Comment: I upvote it, Any update!!!!! To accept the answer